# PowerBI visualization editing

Tags: powerbi

I have this `Line and clustered column chart` visual. On `Shared axis` I have `Competition` on the left and `Other organization` on the right ( same table ). On `Column series` I have `Week` table (13.01.2019 etc...) and on `Column values` I have the numberal value. ( 3 different tables in total ) Now what I need is it to show data side by side. For example I need week 13.01.2019 `Competition` and `Other organization` data side by side not one on the left and other on the right. ( So the first value 41M from `Competition` and 10M from `Other organization` would be next to each other and so on with every week. If anyone could point out what to do or provide me with some documents to read would be great. I don't even know where to start by googling it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just created 2 different visualizations and swapped Shared axis and Column series data fields.